Point in polygon (with holes) algorithm
I am working on a CAD addon, where I needed a function() which tells me if the point is inside a polygon or not. I have already found some good solutions for it, but none of them worked for me perfectly, since when there are holes in the polygon, the original method can return false answers. I figured it out and it's working me perfectly so I wanted to share my code if somebody needs it.  Reviews and critics are welcome. (I had to turn the code back from my API environment to STL, differences may occur.)
https://imgur.com/QOPcogW

My problem with the old method link: the coordinates following each other in the array can lead to false answers, since - for me at least - all of my polygons coordinates were in the same array (including the main polygon and the sub-polygons). The old method checks every side, therefore the "lines" between the main polygon and every subpolygon, which is bad. See for example the line between p11 and p12:
So we need more data for the polygon where we check the sub-polygons too. Besides the coordinates (coords) we need to know the number of polygons (nSubpolys) (if =1 then there's no subpolygon) and where their last vertices are (pends).
If the point is inside of those sub-polygons somewhere we can surely say the point is outside. If the point is inside the main polygon, but is in none of the sub-polygons, it's inside.
See my code here:
struct Point2D
{
    double x;
    double y;
};

struct PolygonData
{
    std::vector<Point2D> coords;  // list of 2d coordinates, coordinates are duplicated for the end-nodes for each subcontour!
                                  // for example a triangle: (1) 0,0; (2) 1.2,3.5; (3) 2.4,7.7; (4) 0,0;
    int nSubPolys;                // number of polyongs, the first is always the main polygon
    std::vector<int> pends;       // contour ends, indicates the vertices which are closing the subcontours
};

// "old method" i have found on stackoverflow
bool IsPointInsidePolygon(const Point2D& p, const std::vector<Point2D>& polygonCoords)
{
    double minX = 0.0;
    double maxX = 0.0;
    double minY = 0.0;
    double maxY = 0.0;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < polygonCoords.size(); i++)
    {
        minX = std::min(polygonCoords[i].x, minX);
        maxX = std::max(polygonCoords[i].x, maxX);
        minY = std::min(polygonCoords[i].y, minY);
        maxY = std::max(polygonCoords[i].y, maxY);
    }

    if (p.x < minX || p.x > maxX || p.y < minY || p.y > maxY)
        return false;

    bool inside = false;
    for (std::size_t i = 0, j = polygonCoords.size() - 1; i < polygonCoords.size(); j = i++)
    {
        if ((polygonCoords[i].y > p.y) != (polygonCoords[j].y > p.y) &&
            p.x < (polygonCoords[j].x - polygonCoords[i].x) * (p.y - polygonCoords[i].y) / (polygonCoords[j].y - polygonCoords[i].y) + polygonCoords[i].x)
        {
            inside = !inside;
        }
    }

    return inside;
}   // IsPontInsidePolygon()

// new method
bool IsPointInsidePolygon(const Point2D& p, const PolygonData& polygonData)
{
    double minX = 0.0;
    double maxX = 0.0;
    double minY = 0.0;
    double maxY = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < polygonData.pends[0]; i++)
    {
        minX = std::min(polygonData.coords[i].x, minX);
        maxX = std::max(polygonData.coords[i].x, maxX);
        minY = std::min(polygonData.coords[i].y, minY);
        maxY = std::max(polygonData.coords[i].y, maxY);
    }

    if (p.x < minX || p.x > maxX || p.y < minY || p.y > maxY)
        return false;

    // check main polygon
    bool inside = false;
    for (int i = 0, j = polygonData.pends[0] - 1; i < polygonData.pends[0]; j = i++)
    {
        if ((polygonData.coords[i].y > p.y) != (polygonData.coords[j].y > p.y) &&
            p.x < (polygonData.coords[j].x - polygonData.coords[i].x) * (p.y - polygonData.coords[i].y) /
            (polygonData.coords[j].y - polygonData.coords[i].y) + polygonData.coords[i].x)
        {
            inside = !inside;
        }
    }

    // we must check for subpolygons too if the point is inside the main polygon
    bool subInside = false;
    if (inside == true && polygonData.nSubPolys > 1)
    {
        int ind = 0;
        int prevPolySize = polygonData.pends[0];
        int actPolySize = 0;

        // skip 1st, because its the main polygon himself
        for (int ii = 2; ii <= polygonData.nSubPolys; ii++)
        {
            std::vector<API_Coord> actPolyCoords;
            ind = 0;

            actPolySize = polygonData.pends[ii] - polygonData.pends[ii - 1];
            std::vector<int>    pends;
            pends.push_back(actPolySize);

            for (int jj = prevPolySize; jj < polygonData.pends[ii - 1]; jj++)
            {
                Point2D actCoord;
                actCoords.x = polygonData.coords[jj].x;
                actCoords.y = polygonData.coords[jj].y;

                actPolyCoords.push_back(actCoord);
                ind++;
            }
            prevPolySize += ind;

            if (IsPointInsidePolygon(p, actPolyCoords)) // call the "old method" (which is not checking subpolygons)
                subInside = true;
        }

        if (subInside)
            inside = false;
    }

    return inside;
}   // IsPontInsidePolygon()


I have tested it, and I am using from now on; it's working

I posted originally on stack overflow, then all of the commenters pointed out that i should come here with my code and downvoted me / sent me away... and my code is working!

Avoid premature optimization
The first thing you do in IsPointInsidePolygon() is to calculate a bounding box for the polygon and check if the point is inside it. While this might be slightly simpler than doing the actual polygon check, I am not sure it is worth it. I would remove it unless you have some data backing up that it improves performance.
If it does, then instead of recalculating the bounding box every time, it might be worth calculating the bounding box at polygon creation time, and then store it along the polygon.
Use std::span to pass a range of coordinates
Instead of passing a pointer to a container, consider using std::span to pass a range of coordinates. This allows you to call a IsPointInsidePolygon() with a subspan of the whole coords. If you can't use C++20 yet, you can pass a pointer to the first coordinate and a count, or alternatively just two iterators.
Avoid code duplication
The first part of code inside the second overload of IsPointInsidePolygon() is identical to that of the first overload. Why not reuse it? Consider:
bool IsPointInsidePolygon(const Point2D& p, std::span<Point2D> polygonCoords)
{
    bool inside = false;

    for (std::size_t i = 0, j = polygonCoords.size() - 1; i < polygonCoords.size(); j = i++)
    {
        if ((polygonCoords[i].y > p.y) != (polygonCoords[j].y > p.y) &&
            p.x < (polygonCoords[j].x - polygonCoords[i].x) * (p.y - polygonCoords[i].y) / (polygonCoords[j].y - polygonCoords[i].y) + polygonCoords[i].x)
        {
            inside = !inside;
        }
    }

    return inside;
}

bool IsPointInsidePolygon(const Point2D& p, const PolygonData& polygonData)
{
    // exit early if the point is not inside the main polygon
    std::span mainPolygon = {
        polygonData.begin(),
        polygonData.begin() + polygondata.pends[0]
    };

    if (!IsPointInsidePolygon(p, mainPolygon) {
        return false;
    }

    // check all subpolygons
    for (std::size_t i = 1; i < polygonData.nSubPolys; ++i)
    {
        std::span subPolygon = {
            polygonData.begin() + polygonData.pends[i - 1],
            polygonData.begin() + polygonData.pends[i]
        };

        if (IsPointInsidePolygon(p, subPolygon)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

Alternative ways to store polygons
Your solution to store polygons with holes in them is to store them basically as multiple polygons; the first one is the main one which is filled, and the subsequent ones only ever remove area from the first one. Besides all the coordinates of the vertices, you also need a vector to store where each polygon stops and the next one begins.
Alternatively, you can store it as a single polygon with no subpolygons. To "fake" two disjoint polygons, consider that you can just connect two polygons with a zero-width bridge. For example, if you have two triangles, with vertices 1, 2, 3 making up the first triangle, and 4, 5, 6 making up the second triangle, you can connect vertices 3 and 4 with an edge going both ways. So you would store the vertices in this order:
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 1
To make a polygon with a hole, again consider these two triangles, but just changes the coordinates of vertices 4, 5, 6 of the second triangle so that they all lie within the first triangle. Whether that second triangle is additive or subtractive can be changes by changing the winding order of its vertices (ie, clockwise vs. anti-clockwise).
The amount of data you have to store is very close to how much you are storing now. One big advantage is that the algorithm is much simpler (you just need to loop over all the points once, no need to treat it as several subpolygons). It handles more polygon shapes (self-intersecting ones, disjoint ones), but the drawback is that it cannot exit early after just checking the "main" polygon, as there is no such concept anymore.

Thanks for the excellent thoughts! sadly we are stuck at c++14, therefore i cannot try it with std::span, will try the other methods. I removed the boundbox checks and found out they are unnecessary, code still works! i gained like 20 ms, down from 1200 with the removal on a somewhat big test polygon. Gonna come back with the code updates!

so, because our API environment is based on C++14, i cannot use std::span, but i figured out, how to pass certain parts (range) of an already existing array to a function. With this method my code became even more simplier, big thanks to @G. Sliepen! I accepted his method an answer!
